# Hide an element when another is set on display block with javascript

Tags: javascript, hide, display

I would like that when one element is visible, another is not seen.

In my case I would like that when you see the pop up, the red arrow is hidden.
I tried to insert this js, but I don't understand where I am wrong:

```
function pop() {
   if (document.getElementsByClassName("spu-bg").style.display == "block") {
   document.getElementsByClassName("opn").style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

can you help me?

[image]

Comment: use `document.getElementsByClassName("spu-bg")[0].style.display`

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("spu-bg")` returns an array

Comment: Duplicate: [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)